# Event Click Element not interactable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

.Running my Selenium Script
I got the error:

```
**selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable**
```

What am I doing wrong?

**CODE**:

```
oCheckBox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='para-mim']")
oCheckBox.click()
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="para-quem" id="para-mim" value="para-mim">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='para-mim']").click()
```

Comment: returned a different error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method": "xpath", "selector": "// option [@ value = 'for me']"}

Answer (score 0):

Try use `.execute_script`:

```
oCheckBox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='para-mim']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", oCheckBox)
```

Or use `ActionChains`:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

oCheckBox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='para-mim']")
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element(oCheckBox).click(oCheckBox).perform()
```